# Rasberry pi - force raspivid to quit

Tags: python, command-line, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

The idea was to use my RBP as a baby monitor that would stream over the network so that I could watch from any computer/TV at home.

1.To begin with, I was trying to stream a video from my raspberry pi to be access from another PC using VLC Network Stream.

It worked using this **command line** :

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 800 -h 400 -fps 24 |cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout'#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8160}' :demux=h264
```

2. After that i wanted it to start from a python program.
   Done using that simple program:

```
    from subprocess import call

    call(["raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 800 -h 400 -fps 24 |cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8160}' :demux=h264"])
```

3. Now it needed to launch the python program at startup. So I created a .desktop file in autostart:

```
mkdir /home/pi/.config/autostart
nano /home/pi/.config/autostart/autostartCamStream.desktop
```

**autostartCamStream.desktop** :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=AutostartCam
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/startCamStream.py
```

Everything is doing exactly what it is supposed to do! On reboot, the startCamStream.py start streaming and I can access it over my VLC player on my PC on port 8160.

But the problem is that on the Raspberry pi, **the stream is full screen and I cant close it or do anything else**... Ive try **CRTL+Q**, **ATL+F4** etc. Nothing is working (I cant even see a terminal, the recording seems to be in front of every other programs) Before the autostart, I was closing the stream using **CTRL-C** since it was running in a terminal.

As I only have basic knowledge in linux environment, I was wondering if anyone has a pretty obvious solution I wouldn't know about... Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just adding -n to the raspivid command solved the problem.

-n stops the video being previewed.